# modifying a column containing both string and number

Tags: awk, sed

I have a tab-delimited file as

```
[ moleculetype ]
; Name nrexcl
AL7 3

[ atoms ]
; nr type resnr resid atom cgnr charge mass
   1 CB   1  AL6 C4      1 -0.1435  12.0110
   2 CB   1  AL6 C5      2 -0.1500  12.0110
   3 CB   1  AL6 C6      3 -0.1500  12.0110
   4 CB   1  AL6 C7      4  0.0825  12.0110
   5 CB   1  AL6 O8      5 -0.1500  12.0110

[ bonds ]
; ai aj fu b0 kb, b0 kb
 16   7 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
 15   7 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
  7   8 1 0.14180  303937.5  0.14180  303937.5
  7  17 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
  8   9 1 0.13550  349343.9  0.13550  349343.9
 20  12 1 0.10190  390836.6  0.10190  390836.6
```

I want the output as

```
[ moleculetype ]
; Name nrexcl
AL7 3

[ atoms ]
; nr type resnr resid atom cgnr charge mass
   1 CB   1  AL6 C      1 -0.1435  12.0110
   2 CB   1  AL6 C      2 -0.1500  12.0110
   3 CB   1  AL6 C      3 -0.1500  12.0110
   4 CB   1  AL6 C      4  0.0825  12.0110
   5 CB   1  AL6 O      5 -0.1500  12.0110

[ bonds ]
; ai aj fu b0 kb, b0 kb
 16   7 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
 15   7 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
  7   8 1 0.14180  303937.5  0.14180  303937.5
  7  17 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
  8   9 1 0.13550  349343.9  0.13550  349343.9
 20  12 1 0.10190  390836.6  0.10190  390836.6
```

where the section under [ atoms ] is modified. The fifth column is modified containing only the strings and not numbers. Please suggest a way out of this.

The problem is that the normal awk function cannot be applied as the fifth column not only contains C6/C7/O8 but also other things as can be seen under [ bonds ].  I have tried with grep and awk as

grep -A307 -P 'atoms' filename | awk -F, 'sub("*[0-9]+\s"*"",$9)' OFS=,

But it is taking the whole file which is not desired.

Comment: Your expected result does not keep the original position for the follow up columns. Is that correct/desired? In other words, the spacing between the fields doesn't matter?

Comment: The spacing for the follow up columns does matter. I want the formatting to be same as the original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\[/h;G;/\n\[ atoms \]/{/^;|^$/!{s/(\S)\S*/\1/5}};P;d' file
```

Make a copy of any line beginning `[` in the hold space.

Append the hold space to every line.

If the second line begins `[ atoms]`, process the line, otherwise print the first line and delete the remainder.

If the start of the current line is either `;` or empty, print the first line and delete the remainder.

Otherwise, replace the fifth field with its first character.

Print the first line and delete the remainder.

Comment: Can you break the code and explain it a little further ? It will be highly useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN {   FS = "\t"
>                ORS = RS RS
>                         RS = "" 
>
> } gsub(FS "[A-Z][0-9]" FS, "&\3") gsub("..\3", FS)'  
>                                  ^
>                                  intentional string-concat
> ```

```
[ moleculetype ]
; Name nrexcl
AL7 3

[ atoms ]
;  nr     type    resnr  resid    atom   cgnr   charge       mass
   1      CB      1      AL6      C      1      -0.1435      12.0110
   2      CB      1      AL6      C      2      -0.1500      12.0110
   3      CB      1      AL6      C      3      -0.1500      12.0110
   4      CB      1      AL6      C      4       0.0825      12.0110
   5      CB      1      AL6      O      5      -0.1500      12.0110

[ bonds ]
;  ai      aj      fu     b0           kb,       b0        kb
   16       7      1      0.10930      287014.9  0.10930   287014.9
   15       7      1      0.10930      287014.9  0.10930   287014.9
    7       8      1      0.14180      303937.5  0.14180   303937.5
    7      17      1      0.10930      287014.9  0.10930   287014.9
    8       9      1      0.13550      349343.9  0.13550   349343.9
   20      12      1      0.10190      390836.6  0.10190   390836.6
```

but this solution has 1 downside effect of 1 extra trailing `\n`.

—  use `sed` to trim it off if necessary

if you really wanna use `awk` to trim it instead, then something like

```
gawk '
BEGIN {       FS = "\t"
       _+=_^= __ = RS RS
                      RS = ""
}
gsub( FS "[A-Z][0-9]" FS, "&\3") \
                     gsub("..\3", FS) (ORS = substr(__, _^(_ < NR)) )'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
     BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} 
     /^; nr/,/^$/{
         if(n=match($0,/ [A-Z][0-9] /)) 
            $(n+2)=" "
     }
'1 inputfile

[ moleculetype ]
; Name nrexcl
AL7 3

[ atoms ]
; nr type resnr resid atom cgnr charge mass
   1 CB   1  AL6 C       1 -0.1435  12.0110
   2 CB   1  AL6 C       2 -0.1500  12.0110
   3 CB   1  AL6 C       3 -0.1500  12.0110
   4 CB   1  AL6 C       4  0.0825  12.0110
   5 CB   1  AL6 O       5 -0.1500  12.0110

[ bonds ]
; ai aj fu b0 kb, b0 kb
 16   7 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
 15   7 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
  7   8 1 0.14180  303937.5  0.14180  303937.5
  7  17 1 0.10930  287014.9  0.10930  287014.9
  8   9 1 0.13550  349343.9  0.13550  349343.9
 20  12 1 0.10190  390836.6  0.10190  390836.6
```

Comment: Can you explain the awk liner by breaking the lines ? It will be highly useful.